# io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: netty

My problem is that I get this kind of exception sometimes:

```
    [nioEventLoopGroup-2-6] WARN io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:780)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:359)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:460)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:579)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:280)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readGroup(CodedInputStream.java:240)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:488)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(AbstractMessage.java:508)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$ExtendableMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:661)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload.<init>(ProtocolMessages.java:5299)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload.<init>(ProtocolMessages.java:5282)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtocolMessages.java:5452)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtocolMessages.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:182)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.protobuf.ProtobufDecoder.decode(ProtobufDecoder.java:114)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.protobuf.ProtobufDecoder.decode(ProtobufDecoder.java:62)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    ... 15 more
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-6] WARN eu.domain.netty.handler.ClientConnectResponseHandler - Exception caught during RPC connection handshake.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:780)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:359)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:460)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:579)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:280)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readGroup(CodedInputStream.java:240)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:488)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(AbstractMessage.java:508)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$ExtendableMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:661)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload.<init>(ProtocolMessages.java:5299)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload.<init>(ProtocolMessages.java:5282)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtocolMessages.java:5452)
    at eu.domain.netty.protobuf.ProtocolMessages$WirePayload$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtocolMessages.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:182)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.protobuf.ProtobufDecoder.decode(ProtobufDecoder.java:114)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.protobuf.ProtobufDecoder.decode(ProtobufDecoder.java:62)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    ... 15 more
```

Sounds like partial parsing of protobuf messages fails. I guess, this is something on Netty encoding/decoding level. 
Can I get some comments on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: my problem was in decoder:

```
out.add(MyMessage.parseFrom(buf));
```

where buf was zero length array

UPD2: there is chance that message was corrupted, so decoder was unable to decode, or maybe it is bug in coder/decoder realisation (?!)